# Load V3 Audio Unit in process on iOS?

Tags: core-audio

When instantiating an Audio Unit with:

```
 [AVAudioUnit instantiateWithComponentDescription:componentDescription
                                             options:kAudioComponentInstantiation_LoadInProcess
                                   completionHandler:^ (AVAudioUnit * __nullable audioUnit, NSError * __nullable error)
```

I'm attempting to load it in process using `options:kAudioComponentInstantiation_LoadInProcess`, but I get the following error:

> kAudioComponentInstantiation_LoadInProcess' is unavailable: not available on iOS

Is is in fact the case that Audio Units cannot be loaded in process on iOS apps?  I would have thought that the opposite would have been the case.  That out of process might be enabled on macOS but not on iOS due to memory, or cpu limitations or something.

Of course the horrendous, fragmented, and highly advanced Core Audio documentation doesn't avail me of the truth here.  So is it in fact the case that its mandatory to created an App Extension to run custom Audio Units in an iOS app?